# Reformulate the Set S, Knapsack problem with tighter bounds.

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, binary-programming

I have the following problem assigned to me. (I found out it was from Conforti- Zambelli Integer Programming Book, Exercise 2.1)

[image]

Can someone please help me how to proceed. I am stuck with this and am not able to think of anything. Have been working on this problem for hours now. Otherwise, I wouldn't have asked since it is a homework problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S\stackrel{\rm def}{=}\{ x\in\{0,1\}^4: 2x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4\leq 3\}$, and $S'\stackrel{\rm def}{=}\{ x\in\{0,1\}^4: 2x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4\leq 3,\ x_1+x_2+x_3\leq 2,\ x_1+x_2+x_4\leq 2,\ x_1+x_3+x_4\leq 2\}$.

Clearly, $S'\subseteq S$, so it suffices to prove $S\subseteq S'$.

By contradiction, suppose $S\setminus S' \neq \emptyset$, and let $x\in S\setminus S'$. This means at least one of the 3 "new" constraints is violated by $x$. Without loss of generality, assume $x_1+x_2+x_3 > 2$ *(without loss of generality, because of the symmetry).*

Then, since $x_1,x_2,x_3\in\{0,1\}$ by definition of $S$, we have that the integer $x_1+x_2+x_3$ satisfies
$$2<x_1+x_2+x_3 \leq 3$$
that is $x_1+x_2+x_3=3$; from which $x_1=x_2=x_3=1$.

But then, $2x_1+x_2+x_3 = 2+1+1=4 > 3$, and $x\notin S$ — contradiction.

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more on the statement "Then, since x1, x2, x3 ... to the Eqn 2 < x1 + x2 + x3<=3 ". Also, what was the rationale behind selecting such S and S'?

Comment: @Manish each x_i is either 0 or 1. So their sum is an integer between 0 and 3: since it it greater than 2, it must be 3.

Comment: Okay.. I thought maybe you used something else.

Comment: Did you deliberately didn't write x4 in S and 1st equation of S'?

Comment: @Manish Nope, I just forgot it. Fixed, thanks!